# В "ознакомьтесь с справкой" заменить предлог на "со"

Tags: дефект, локализация

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Традусёр открывается нынче только по vpn, нет возможности на данный момент самому там посмотреть эту строку.

Comment: @älёxölüt а воз и ныне там...

Comment: Зато теперь по VPN :)