# Закрытые как дубликат вопросы не засчитываются для значка "сократ"?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-так-задумано, знаки, дубликаты

Заметил, что вопрос [В "ознакомьтесь с справкой" заменить предлог на "со"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8492/15479) не учёлся для [image]

В треде [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/260198) я не вижу особого упоминания этого пункта.

Хотя в треде [Do duplicate questions count as "well-received" for the Curious, Inquisitive, and Socratic badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306175/260198) ɪBᴜɢ цитирует пункт из того ответа:

> Any open question that is not deleted and has a score >= 1 is considered well-received

Но эта часть была изменена в ревизии 103 (https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/67399/revisions#):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял отсюда [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/260198):

> A well-received question is one that's **open**, **not deleted**, and has a score > 0

Все закрытые вопросы не учитываются независимо от причины, не только дубликаты.